# Efficent way to manage 100 items in C with little overhead

Tags: c, optimization, data-structures, binary-tree

I am on a system with only about 512kb available to my application (the rest is used for buffers). I need to be as efficient as possible.

I have about 100 items that are rapidly added/deleted from a list. What is an efficient way to store these in C and is there a library (with a good license) that will help? The list never grows above 256 items and its average size is 15 items.

- Should I use a Binary Search Tree?
- Red Black Tree

Comment: You say a list of 100 items, then mention 256 max. Do you mean there are (no more than) 100 different items, but each might occur more than once? As for efficiency, do you want to minimize memory usage or CPU time?

Comment: Can you tell us how you will be using this list? Do you need arbitrary-index access? Do you need deletions from the middle of the list, or just end-to-end? Is a deletion always going to be followed by an addition? etc.

Comment: It sounds like what you **don't** want is anything that does *malloc* / *free*, directly or indirectly, with any frequency. If the max number of items is 256, and the average is 15, just make an array of size 256 and keep your items in that. KISS. Dynamic memory allocation is for when you have uncertainty about your maximum storage needs.

Comment: I need random-access, especially quick random inserts and deletions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is no longer then 256, the best option will be to hold a hash table and add/remove each new element with hash function. this way each add/remove will take you only O(1), and the size of the used memory doesn't need to be large.

Comment: I would go for a hash table too.

Answer (score 4):

With an average size of 15, all these other solutions are unnecessary overkill; a simple dynamic *array* is best here. Searching is a linear pass over the array and insertion and deletion requires moving all elements behind the insertion point. *But still* this moving around will be offset by the lack of overhead for so few elements.

Even better, since you’re doing a linear search anyway, deleting at arbitrary points can be done by swapping the last element to the deleted position so no further moving around of elements is required – yielding O(1) for insertion and deletion and O(very small n) for lookup.

Comment: And lest somebody point out that “O(very small n)” is not meaningful, *that was a joke*.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a doubly-linked-list. When dealing with tens or hundreds of items, its not terribly slower to search than an array, and it has the advantage of only taking up as much space as it absolutely needs. Adding and removing elements is very simple, and incurs very little additional overhead.

A tree structure is faster for searching, but has more overhead when adding or removing elements. That said, when dealing with tens or hundreds of items, the difference probably isn't significant. If I were you, I'd build an implementation of each and see which one is faster in actual usage.

Answer (score 1):

15 items, BST should be fine if you can keep them sorted, not sure if the overhead will be much better than a linked list or an array if the items are rather small. For a lot of insertions/deletions I recommend a linked list because the only thing you have to do is patch pointers.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with a plain old array? You said "list" so presumably order is important, so you can't use a hash set (if you do use a hash set, use probing, not chaining).

You can't use a linked list because it would double your memory requirements. A tree would have the same problem, and it would be much more difficult to implement.

Comment: Why would a linked list double the memory requirements? If the OP is storing structs, then the overhead of having pointers could be quite small compared to the data being stored. In addition, an array would result in wasted space (e.g. allocating a 256 element array, but only using it to store 15 elements).

Comment: @quanticle: A list uses pointers. A double-linked list on 32-bit arch is 8 bytes extra per item.

Comment: ++ Absolutely. Keep it simple^3, for that number of items.